# $(n-1) i_{n-2}-(n-1) i_n$

Tags: calculus

I think I have lost my brain, but I cant see this $$(n-1) i_{n-2}-(n-1) i_n$$

Transposing $-(n-1) i_n$ we get $ni_n=(n-1) i_{n-2}$, I just cant believe I am even asking this but could someone show what I am missing?

As you probably all ready know, this is the reduction formula.

[image]

Comment: Please explain your notation and which reduction formula you are referring to.

Comment: I have added a scan from the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion is understandable; I can't say I've ever seen the word "transposing" used that way before. The equation is
$$I_n=(n-1)I_{n-2}-(n-1)I_n$$
The author is adding $(n-1)I_n$ to both sides (that's apparently what they mean by "transposing") to obtain
$$nI_n=(n-1)I_{n-2}$$

Comment: Cant believe that the word transpose could throw me so easily off track.Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @ALEXANDER You're welcome.